# qml listview does not update information after datachanged() signal

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I have a model written based on this [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-abstractitemmodel-example.html). This model is connected to a `listview` to display dynamic data. I have made sure the model's `datachanged()` signal is emitted whenever the source data is being changed. **The list view does not update on the datachanged() signal**. Here is my code:

**DataModel.h:**

```
class DataList {
    public:
        DataList(const QString &name, const QString &value, const QString &category);

        QString name() const;
        QString value() const;
        QString category() const;

    private:
        QString m_name;
        QString m_value;
        QString m_category;
};

class DataModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        enum AVRoles {
            NameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
            ValueRole,
            CategoryRole
        };

        DataModel(QAbstractItemModel *parent = 0);
        virtual ~DataModel() {}
        void addData(const DataList &datalist);
        int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

        QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    protected:
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

    private:
        QList<DataList> m_datalist;

    public slots:
        void onInitialPolygonAreaChanged(qreal);

};
```

**DataModel.cpp:**

```
DataList::DataList(const QString &name, const QString &value, const QString &category) {
    m_name = name;
    m_value = value;
    m_category = category;
}

QString DataList::name() const {
    return m_name;    
}

QString DataList::value() const {
    return m_value;
}

QString DataList::category() const {
    return m_category;
}


DataModel::DataModel(QAbstractItemModel *parent) :
    QAbstractListModel(parent) {    
}

void DataModel::addData(const DataList &datalist){
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_datalist << datalist;
    endInsertRows();    
}

int DataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_datalist.count();
}

QVariant DataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_datalist.count())
            return QVariant();
    const DataList &datalist = m_datalist[index.row()];

    if(role ==NameRole )
        return datalist.name();
    else if(role == ValueRole)
        return datalist.value();
    else if(role == CategoryRole)
        return datalist.category();

    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> DataModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[NameRole] = "name";
    roles[ValueRole] = "value";
    roles[CategoryRole] = "category";
    return roles;
}

void DataModel::onInitialPolygonAreaChanged(qreal ) {
    //0 is the index of iPA
    qDebug() << "IPA from model" ;
    QVector<int> roleVector;
    roleVector.append(ValueRole);
    roleVector.append(NameRole);
    roleVector.append(CategoryRole);
    roleVector.append(Qt::DisplayRole);       
    emit dataChanged(index(0),index(0),roleVector);
}
```

**Mainwindow.cpp:**

```
model.addData(DataList(QString("Initial Polygon Area"),QString::number(av1.initialPolygonArea()) + " sq.km",QString("Area")));

View->rootContext()->setContextProperty("AVModel",&model);               

connect(&av1,SIGNAL(initialPolygonAreaChanged(qreal)),&model,SLOT(onInitialPolygonAreaChanged(qreal)));
```

**view.qml:**

```
ListView {
    id: view
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

    width: parent.width
    model: AVModel
    delegate: Text { text: name + "     " + value; font.pixelSize: 18 ; color: "white"}
}
```

Comment: You emit `dataChanged` for cell (0,0) but not actually data was changed. Reimplement `setData` and so emit `dataChanged` after data was really  changed.

Comment: If i reimplement setdata, will it not add multiple rows of the same data?

Comment: Aside from folibis finding that you emit the signal for the first row, where in the code does it actually change the data?
The view can only react to the change signal by retrieving the value anew, if the value has not changed the display won't change either.

Comment: connect(&av1,SIGNAL(initialPolygonAreaChanged(qreal)),&model,SLOT(onInitialPolygonAreaChanged(qreal)));

I am changing the data and verifying that this slot onInitialPolygonAreaChanged(qreal) is being called which means datachanged() is called. I am doing only for 1st row because only that row is being changed.